# How to correctly parse arguments with Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn how to work with `IO` in Haskell by writing a function that, if there is a flag, will take a list of points from a file, and if there is no flag, it asks the user to enter them.

```
dispatch :: [String] -> IO ()
dispatch argList  = do
  if "file" `elem` argList
    then do
       let (path : otherArgs) = argList
       points <- getPointsFile path

    else
      print "Enter a point in the format: x;y"
      input <- getLine
      if (input == "exit")
        then do
          print "The user inputted list:"
          print $ reverse xs
        else (inputStrings (input:xs))

    if "help" `elem` argList
      then help
      else return ()
dispatch [] = return ()
dispatch _ = error "Error: invalid args"

getPointsFile :: String -> IO ([(Double, Double)])
getPointsFile path = do
  handle <- openFile path ReadMode
  contents <- hGetContents handle
  let points_str = lines contents
  let points = foldl (\l d -> l ++ [tuplify2 $ splitOn ";" d]) [] points_str
  hClose handle
  return points
```

I get this: `` do-notation in pattern Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?` after `if "file" `elem` argList ``.

I'm also worried about the binding issue, assuming that I have another flag that says which method will be used to process the points. Obviously it waits for points, but I don't know how to make points visible not only in if then else, constructs. In imperative languages I would write something like:

```
init points
if ... { points = a}
else points = b
some actions with points
```

How I can do something similar in Haskell?

Comment: Work with IO by *avoiding* it for as long as possible. You can define `getPoints :: String -> [(Double, Double)]` to parse *any* newline-delimited string, then `getPointsFile` is simply `fmap getPoints . readFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly minimal example that I've done half a dozen times when I'm writing something quick and dirty, don't have a complicated argument structure, and so can't be bothered to do a proper job of setting up one of the usual command-line parsing libraries. It doesn't explain what went wrong with your approach -- there's an existing good answer there -- it's just an attempt to show what this kind of thing looks like when done idiomatically.

```
import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    pts <- case args of
        ["--help"] -> usage stdout ExitSuccess
        ["--file", f] -> getPointsFile f
        [] -> getPointsNoFile
        _ -> usage stderr (ExitFailure 1)
    print (frobnicate pts)

usage :: Handle -> ExitCode -> IO a
usage h c = do
    nm <- getProgName
    hPutStrLn h $ "Usage: " ++ nm ++ " [--file FILE]"
    hPutStrLn h $ "Frobnicate the points in FILE, or from stdin if no file is supplied."
    exitWith c

getPointsFile :: FilePath -> IO [(Double, Double)]
getPointsFile = {- ... -}

getPointsNoFile :: IO [(Double, Double)]
getPointsNoFile = {- ... -}

frobnicate :: [(Double, Double)] -> Double
frobnicate = {- ... -}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do something similar, if there are also flags d and n, which work with points, just now the code supports only 1 flag and it concerns only what is stored in points, so I do not know how to write it nicely

Comment: @student422 I'm not sure I understand fully. Is simply adding another case to the `case args of ...` bit sufficient? If not, why not?

Comment: Okay, I need the points to make an approximation with them, the approximation can be done with more than one method and the user chooses which one, flags them. If we add another flag to the proposed area, we get another function that reads points but doesn't process them

Comment: Say there could be several flags, for example:  `myprogram --file --linearAprox`

Comment: @student422 Okay. At that point I'd switch from a manual `case`, like above, to using a library for parsing command lines. I like optparse-applicative, though it definitely is a bit of an investment to get started with it.

Answer (score 0):

`if` in Haskell doesn't inherently have anything to do with control flow, it just switches between *expressions*. Which, in Haskell, happen to include `do` blocks of statements (if we want to call them that), but you still always need to make that explicit, i.e. you need to say both `then do` and `else do` if there are multiple statements in each branch.

Also, all the statements *in* a `do` block need to be indented to the same level. So in your case

```
  if "file" `elem` argList
       ...
  if "help" `elem` argList
```

Or alternatively, if the `help` check should only happen in the `else` branch, it needs to be indented to the statements in that `do` block.

Independent of all that, I would recommend to avoid parsing anything in an `IO` context. It is usually much less hassle and easier testable to first parse the strings into a pure data structure, which can then easily be processed by the part of the code that does IO. There are libraries like [cmdargs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs) and [optparse-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) that help with the parsing part.

Comment: The Haskell reports calls the elements of a do block "stmts" in its official grammar. I think that's a pretty good source for accepting "statements" as valid. https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14